# Large remainder upon non-integer division

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $0 < r < 1$. Does there always exist $s<r$ such that $s=1/n$ for some positive integer $n$, and the remainder when dividing $r$ by $s$ is at least $0.99s$?

(As usual, we define the quotient as the largest integer $k$ such that $ks\leq r$, and the remainder as $r-ks$.)

This feels somewhat similar to the result about the [density of the fractional part](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-prove-that-fractional-part-of-nx-n-in-mathbb-N-is-dense-in-0-1-where-x-is-an-irrational-number), but I'm not sure if there is any formal connection.

Comment: How do you define the *remainder* of the division between reals ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust, you can define the quotient as the largest integer $k$ such that $ks<r$, and then define the remainder as the difference.

Comment: Be aware that this is not a standard definition and don't assume we know it.

Comment: You are right, but maybe seeing $\Bbb Z[r]$ as a euclidean domain gives a natural euclidean division?

Comment: @IsaacRen: we are not deemed to fix incomplete questions by ourselves, are we ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $r$, you want to know if there are non-negative integers $m$ and $n$ for which

$${m+.99\over n}\le r\lt{m+1\over n}$$

Let's rewrite this as $100m+99\le100rn\lt100m+100$.

Now consider the number $r=1/10$. The largest multiple of $10$ less than $100m+100$ is $100m+90$, so the inequality $100m+99\le10n\lt100m+100$ cannot be satisfied. So the answer in general is No.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the result on the density of the fractional part. First, let me rephrase the problem: we want to prove
$$\forall r\in(0,1),\;\forall\varepsilon>0,\;\exists n\in\Bbb N,\;\{nr\}>1-\varepsilon.$$
Indeed, in this case, setting $s=\frac 1n$, the division gives a quotient of $\lfloor nr\rfloor$ and a remainder of $r-\lfloor nr\rfloor s=\frac 1n(nr-\lfloor nr\rfloor)>s(1-\varepsilon)$. Reciprocally, if there exists $s$ leaving a large remainder, then setting $n=\frac 1s$ proves this statement.

Now then, this statement is equivalent to
saying that $1$ is an adherent point of the sequence $(\{nr\})_{n\in\Bbb N}$, which is true if $r$ is irrational by the density of the fractional part. If $r$ is rational and $\frac pq$ is a reduced expression, then as you said in the comments, $s$ exists iff $\varepsilon>\frac 1q$.

Comment: If $r=p/q$ is rational and $\varepsilon < 1/q$, it looks like there won't exist $n$ such that $\{nr\} > 1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, not sure what I was thinking...

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if for any $0<r<1$, one can find a natural $n$ such that

$$nr>1\land \{nr\}\ge\frac{0.99}n.$$

When $n$ increases, the conditions becomes easier and easier, I don't see what could make them impossible to fulfill.

Let the first nonzero decimal of $r$ be the $m^{th}$, then $n=10^{m-1}$ works.

Comment: I don't think you need the condition $nr>1$. And if $r=0.1$, then $\{10r\}=0<\frac{0.99}n$.

Comment: @IsaacRen: that condition belongs to the question.

Comment: Where does it impose $nr>1$?

Comment: @IsaacRen: hem, $s<r$ maybe ?

Comment: ah, of course xD

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, this is fixed. But maybe there are still corner cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107725/discussion-between-isaac-ren-and-yves-daoust).